# Null Check combined with Ternary Expression throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I have the following objects:

```
class Parent
{
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Why does the following code throw a NullReferenceException?

```
var value = parent.Child != null && 
            parent.Child.Type == "test" 
                ? parent.Child.Value == 1 
                : parent.Child.Value == 2;
```

I would think the null-check would block the second part of the conditional from executing.
However the following code works:

```
var value = (parent.Child != null) && 
            (parent.Child.Type == "test" 
                ? parent.Child.Value == 1 
                : parent.Child.Value == 2);
```

So I think some operator precedence is at fault here...

Comment: Why wouldn't it throw that exception?

Comment: That code doesn't even compile? The two return values are different, one returns a bool and the other an int?

Comment: @andyb952 Considering how the ternary operator is used, I assume it's a typo and the second is meant to be `==` rather than `=`.

Comment: First code could be rewritten `(parent.Child != null && parent.Child.Type == "test") ? ...` Check John answer for more details

Comment: @andyb952 it was a type as John suggested

Comment: _"I think some operator precedence is at fault here"_ -- Indeed. But if you already think that, you don't need to ask a question. There's [a documentation page for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence). To reinforce the general idea, there's this statement from the first marked duplicate: [_"you should always assume it's your fault"_](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html).

Comment: Then the link to the documentation was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't it throw a `NullReferenceException`?

```
var value = parent.Child != null && 
    parent.Child.Type == "test" 
        ? parent.Child.Value == 1 
        : parent.Child.Value == 2;
```

Let's rewrite your code with an interim variable:

```
bool condition = parent.Child != null && parent.Child.Type == "test";
var value = condition ? parent.Child.Value == 1 : parent.child.Value == 2;
```

And then with an if statement to make it even clearer:

```
bool value = false;
bool condition = parent.Child != null && parent.Child.Type == "test";
if (condition)
{
    value = parent.Child.Value == 1;
}
else
{
    vaue = parent.Child.Value == 2;
}
```

Your condition requires two things to be true: `parent.Child` isn't null, and `parent.Child.Type` is equal to "test".

If your condition is false, you use the "else" part of the ternary operator: `parent.Child.Value == 2`.

If your condition is false because `parent.Child == null` then you will be trying to access a `null` object's property in your `else` section, thus triggering a `NullReferenceException`.

As for why it's interpreted in this order, see [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) about C# operators and their precedence. As you can see, `a && b` has higher precedence than `a ? b : c`. `a && b` will therefore be executed before `a ? b : c`.

Comment: I see how it works, but I wonder _why_ the statements before the '?' are grouped together even though the complete ternary operator also returns a boolean.

Comment: @Lodewijk because `&&` has higher priority than `?:`.